# how do i make an object cast a shadow on another object

Tags: lighting, shadows

I want to make an object cast a shadow on another, but I don know how[image]

I've got a light with a sphere outside the camera view, I was hoping the sphere would sort of cast some sort of shadow, but it isn't. I'm not sure what to do

to mention, this model is meant to describe day/night

Comment: The environment lighting might be interfering with your ability to create a crisp shadow - click on the world properties tab (little pink globe on the right side) and change the background (world) color from default grey to closer to black.

Comment: if you are in material preview...then open this here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoFJB.png, click on "scene lights" and turn down the strength. If you are in rendered view, follow Christophers comment

Comment: Hello please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/